# Meaning of 増える in this sentence

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence:

> 魚は三匹に増えていた。

I don't know whether to interpret に as **to** or **by**.
So if I start with one fish then:

> The number of fish increased **to** three (there are now three fish), or
>
> The number of fish increased **by** three (there are now four fish)

Which is the correct translation and how would I modify the sentence to make it have the other meaning? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the total number. I.e. now there are 3 fish.

To get the other meaning, you can say 魚が三匹増えた。

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I was thinking was correct, but I wasn't positive.